# Make replace function case-insensitive

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace, case-insensitive

I have a function that replaces text smilies etc. with image emoticons

How can I make this case-INsensitive?
I have tried using "gi" and "ig" at the replacer, but it does'nt seem to make a difference

```
var emots = {
    ':)' : 'smile',
    ':-)' : 'smile',
    ';)' : 'wink',
    ';-)' : 'wink',
    ':(' : 'downer',
    ':-(' : 'downer',
    ':D' : 'happy',
    ':-D' : 'happy',
    '(smoke)' : 'smoke',
    '(y)' : 'thumbsup',
    '(b)' : 'beer',
    '(c)' : 'coffee',
    '(cool)' : 'cool',
    '(hehe)' : 'tooth',
    '(haha)' : 'tooth',
    '(lol)' : 'tooth',
    '(pacman)' : 'pacman',
    '(hmm)' : 'sarcastic',
    '(woot)' : 'woot',
    '(pirate)' : 'pirate',
    '(wtf)' : 'wtf'
};

function smile(str){
    var out = str;
        for(k in emots){
            out = out.replace(k,'<img src="/emoticons/'+emots[k]+'.gif" title="'+k+'" />','g');
        }
    return out;
};
```

Comment: "i" works only in firefox as I see it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
out = out.replace(k,'<img src="/emoticons/'+emots[k]+'.gif" title="'+k+'" />','g');
```

To:

```
out = out.replace(new RegExp(k.replace(/[-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g, "\\$&"), 'ig'), '<img src="/emoticons/'+emots[k]+'.gif" title="'+k+'" />');
```

Regex escaping function taken from this answer [Escape string for use in Javascript regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446170/escape-string-for-use-in-javascript-regex#6969486)

Comment: That inside for(k in emots){) ?

Comment: @mowgli Yes, that's right.  It's just taking the flags out of your replace function and converting them into flags for a regex. `escapeRegExp` escapes all special regex characters, although you really only need to escape `(` and `)` with your inputs, it's better to escape everything in case you add new emoticons that use other characters like `:]` or something later on.

Comment: Ok ;) But Im thinking... is'nt it wrong to create a function inside a loop? It will be created (or checked and not re-created, I dunno) for each letter I guess

Comment: @mowgli Yes, sorry.  Only the one line is in the loop.  I didn't make that clear.  The function just needs to be in the same scope.  Right after your loop would be a good place, or you can get rid of the function altogether. Just replace `escapeRegExp(k)` with `k.replace(/[-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g, "\\$&")`

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit trickier than it appears on the surface. Following is a complete solution. It uses only one regex search on the target string, for simplicity and efficiency.

Note that, because it's case insensitive (e.g., `(hehe)` and `(HeHe)` are treated the same), `:-d` is also treated the same as `:-D`.

```
var emots = {
    ':)' : 'smile',
    ':-)' : 'smile'
    // Add the rest of your emoticons...
};

// Build the regex that will be used for searches
var emotSearch = [];
for (var p in emots) {
    if (emots.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
        emotSearch.push(p.replace(/[-[{()*+?.\\^$|]/g, '\\$&'));
        if (p !== p.toLowerCase()) {
            emots[p.toLowerCase()] = emots[p];
        }
    }
}
emotSearch = RegExp(emotSearch.join('|'), 'gi');

function smile(str) {
    return str.replace(emotSearch, function ($0) {
        var emot = $0.toLowerCase();
        if (emot in emots) {
            return '<img src="/emoticons/' + emots[emot] + '.gif" title="' + $0 + '" />';
        }
        return $0;
    });
}
```

Comment: Wow a lot of code.. Did not try it. The other shorter answer was perfect. And simple is good ;)

Comment: So be it. Just so you're aware, though, the other answer you're referring to requires a separate search-and-replace for every property of emots, which is significantly less efficient and will become slower as you add more emoticons to search for. It also uses a needlessly verbose regex for escaping regex metacharacters.

Answer (score -2):

Or just use .toLowerCase() on the input before you run the check?